# Sync local SQL Express Database over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I know there's a lot of material on this topic, but somehow I really can't find anything not out of date and for my needs.

What I need.

I have a local SQL Express 2008 R2 Database

I need to sync this Database over WCF with a Server Database (SQL 2008 R2)
I ONLY NEED ONE WAY "DOWNLOAD" SYNCHING meaning, that the client Database is always overridden by the Servers.

How can I accomplish that?

I am trying for several days to get it work with the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1.

Thank you!

Comment: And you can't use SQL replication between the two SQL Servers?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, It should go only over the Webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you looked at this sample?

[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)

Comment: Thank you I've looked at it and am using it in my environment now. Its quite cool since, the client's db is being initially created (the schema comes from the WCF server).

Answer (score 0):

If you really won't need any data to go back into your server database from the client, then using MSF2.1 is overkill for what you need. It would probably be faster and easier to build (or find) a tool that makes an "insert or update" stored procedure for every table in your database. With that in place and the proper timestamps and delete flags in every table, you should be able to accomplish it with significantly less overhead than implementing the sync framework.

Also, if you haven't already taken a look at it, have a look at the web sync replication option:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this was also my first thought, but meanwhile I got MSF2.1 working quite easily. I will stick with it for a moment!